# how to compare two datetimepicker values in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have a problem with a `Windows Form` application which has two `DateTimePicker` controls showing **"DATE OF BIRTH"** and **"DATE OF JOINING"**.

I want to compare the values of these controls such that date of birth should be not **less than and not greater than and should not be equal** less than and not greater than and should not be equal...

How can I do this?

Comment: Look at the linked question, basically...

Comment: And if that doesn't help - can't you just fetch the `Value` from each `DateTimePicker` and compare them? What have you tried, and what went wrong?

Comment: I wanted to know how to use greater than and less than comparisons in a winform
If I save my datetime it saves to my database as text(string) as 04/09/2014,If I want to compare these 2 strings in the form ,what to do? @JonSkeet

Comment: What @JonSkeet was suggesting could be shown in my answer.

Comment: From your comment, I would be asking myself as to how you would check if dates are before/after/equal if you have just converted them to strings FROM Date/Time format?

Comment: @ShivaDebrown: Well you just use `foo.Value > bar.Value`... how your data is stored in your database is an entirely different matter. (Your question doesn't even mention a database!) You should change your database schema so that it's *not* using dates...

Comment: Of course , storing data is different matter..BUt trying to explain what I want exactly...and I'm not comparing database values so,didn't mention database @JonSkeet

Comment: for example my company hires employees so that they are less than 30 years old..
if i Select date time picker my message box has to show that one's "age is this  much" so you are not supposed to fit for this position,,,

for this type of problems What to do.. @jbutler483

Comment: @ShivaDebrown - Why must you convert the dates to strings before you compare them?  Why can't you just compare the .Value properties of each DateTimePicker?

Comment: `int year = DateTime.Today.Year - dtpdob.Value.Year;
          int month = DateTime.Today.Month - dtpdob.Value.Month;
          int day = DateTime.Today.Day - dtpdob.Value.Day;
          var a = year.ToString();
          var b = month.ToString();
          var c = day.ToString();
          if (day != 0 && month!=0 && year!=0)
          {
              if(day!=1)
              txtage.Text = a + " Years " + b + " Months " + c + " Days ";
              else
                  txtage.Text = a + " Years " + b + " Months " + c + " Day ";
          }`
will it work for to find age?? @jbutler483

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by  jbutler483

I tried to do but I couldn't get any solution finally as my own knowledge I used following code

```
 private void dtpdob_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      int year = DateTime.Today.Year - dtpdob.Value.Year;
      int month = DateTime.Today.Month - dtpdob.Value.Month;
      int day = DateTime.Today.Day - dtpdob.Value.Day;
      var a = year.ToString();
      var b = month.ToString();
      var c = day.ToString();
      if (day != 0 && month!=0 && year!=0)
      {
          if(day!=1)
          txtage.Text = a + " Years " + b + " Months " + c + " Days ";
          else
              txtage.Text = a + " Years " + b + " Months " + c + " Day ";
      }
      else if (day == 0 && month == 0)
          txtage.Text = a + " Years ";
      else if (day == 0 && month != 0)
          txtage.Text = a + " Years " + b + " Months ";
      else
          txtage.Text = a + " Years " + b + " Months " + c + " Days "; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
DateTimePicker dtBDay = new DateTimePicker();
dtBDay.Value = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-5);
DateTimePicker dtJoin = new DateTimePicker();
dtJoin.Value = DateTime.Now;
if (dtBDay.Value >= dtJoin.Value)
{
    throw new Exception("Date of Join cannot be less than or equal to Date of Birth");
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: for example my company hires employees so that they are less than 30 years old.. if i Select date time picker my message box has to show that one's "age is this much" so you are not supposed to fit for this position,,, for this type of problems What to do.. @karthick

Comment: Use ValueChanged event of the date picker control. From that event you verify the value.