# Comparing Dates using C#'s DateTimePicker

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a constant date of "March 1, 2016" (MMMM dd, yyyy) format. Is there any simple way to determine that my selected date in a DateTimePicker is greater than, less than or equal to the constant date?

Comment: _"Is there any simplier way"_ simpler than what?

Comment: DateTime.ParseExact the constant date string to get a date variable then compare as you would any other two date variables.

Comment: Can't get any simpler than **CompareTo** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ata5aya(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25663033/how-to-compare-two-datetimepicker-values-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple enough ?

```
var fixedDate = new DateTime(2016, 3, 1);
if (myDateTimePicker.Value >= fixedDate) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

My date picker is from WPF for example:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1990, 06, 21);
DateTime selectedDate = (DateTime)((System.Windows.Controls.DatePicker)(sender)).SelectedDate;
if(dt >= selectedDate)
{
}
```